# Request to /api folder from getInitialProps

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless

In my app, I'm sending request from `getInitialProps` to an api endpoint (in /api folder).
When running my app in localhost, everything works, because it's all under same domain (localhost).

After deploying my app successfully to aws lambda (using `serverless-next.js`), those requests doesn't work anymore.
The reason is that the host header when running `getInitialProps` in server, is `myAppBucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, but the app domain is `https://d25q7fh11ll2cg.cloudfront.net`.
request to `myAppBucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/users` doesn't work but to `https://d25q7fh11ll2cg.cloudfront.net/api/users` works.
But I don't have the domain data (i.e `https://d25q7fh11ll2cg.cloudfront.net/api/users`) when running `getInitialProps`.

I don't want to put the domain as an env var. there is another solution for this?
Also, calling directly the handler function from `getInitialProps` is problematic because the handler use a server-side only packages.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I meet a similar use case with you.

First, I suggest you to replace `getInitialProps` by `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` to make sure you call your API from server side.

`getInitialProps` is deprecated, and they may run at **client** or **server side**, so they may cause unexpected behavior for your use case (our api route is server side)

Then from Next.js docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering or https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation), check their small grey box:

```
Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in your application. 
Instead, directly import the API route and call its function yourself. 
You may need to slightly refactor your code for this approach.
```

That means you have to re-organize your logic something like:

```
// A naive axample

pages
  api
    route1.js
      export async function service1()
      export default async function handler(req,res)
        const result = await service1()
        res.json(result);

  my_page.js
    getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
      const result = await import("./api/route1").then(mod => mod.service1());
      return {props: {result}}
```

Yeah, just break down your logic into a blackbox (`service1`) and export them along with the default handler of the API route.

I think the blackbox is a common practice in most frameworks, and also help us in this API route use case.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks! But, I can't use getServerSideProps because I'm using getInitialProps (in HOC wrapper for my pages) to make sure the user is authenticated. How can I do it with getServerSideProps?

Comment: You can solve it by applying the latest practice: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-iron-session May introduce api routes: api/login|logout, useUser hook and especially req.session in Getserversideprops (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/pages/profile-ssr.js)

Comment: Yes, I will not abandon `getInitialProps` until next.js will supply a good alternative for client redirects in getServerSideProps. Even in the example you gave, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/pages/profile-ssr.js, it doesn't implement any client redirection. I will wait for this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14890

Comment: What kind of redirect do you want? The getServerSideProps is server-side, so the redirect is obviously a server redirect, in the example they redirect by set the location with http status 302. If the Next.js's dicussion you provided above is not finished. I think we can do something like in getServerSideProps return a props like `redirectTo`, and in the page component, get that `props.redirectTo` and use the `useRouter` to redirect from client side!

Comment: getInitialProps is not deprecated

Comment: You can read https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps and see how they recommend the usage. I prefer getServerSideProps or getStaticProps to make the behaviours correctly on server side. As they said, after 9.3 we should use others instead of getInitialProps, could it be considered deprecated?